# Angular 2 : Show div on keypress

Tags: angular

I have 3 text box.
If any of the one gets typed then I want a div to be shown and if there I press backspace and make the textbox empty then it should be disappeared.

I have tried below code.

```css
show_div(){
  if(text_1.value == 0 || text_2.value == 0 || text_3.value == 0){
    show_div=false;
  }
  
  else{
  show_div=true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="text_1" [keypress]="show_div()">
<input type="text" name="text_2" [keypress]="show_div()">
<input type="text" name="text_3" [keypress]="show_div()">

<div *ngIf="show_div==true">Div Shown</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
text_1:any;
text_2:any;
text_3:any;

show_div:boolean;

show_div(text_value:any){
    this.text_1 = text_value;
    this.text_2 = text_value;
    this.text_3 = text_value;
    if(this.text_1.length > 0 || this.text_2.length > 0 || this.text_3.length > 0){
      this.show_div = true;
    }
    else{
      this.show_div = false;
    }
  }
  
  
  ngOnInit() {
      this.show_div=false;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="text_1" [(ngModel)]="text_1" (keypress)="show_div(text_1)">
<input type="text" name="text_2" [(ngModel)]="text_2" (keypress)="show_div(text_2)">
<input type="text" name="text_3" [(ngModel)]="text_3" (keypress)="show_div(text_3)">

<div *ngIf="show_div">Div Shown</div>
```

Try this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to help. :)